# Passing the same reactive object to the same shiny module causes "Error: promise already under evaluation"

Tags: r, shiny

**Objective:** I have created a simple reproducible app in which I am attempting to add UI components through an action button so that I can filter the same dataset by the UI filters generated from the action button. I am attempting to use the shiny module code to save the dataset after the filter is applied to it and reuse the filtered dataset the next time the actionbutton is clicked. In other words, I want to reuse this filtered dataset (not the original unfiltered dataset) everytime a new set of UI components are generated by clicking the actionbutton.

**Problem:** The desired outcome works for the first instance when the user clicks the actiobutton, but any sequential click of the actionbutton results in *Error: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?* Is what I am attempting to do not possible in shiny / shiny modules, or am I performing something incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

add.filter.UI = function(id) {

  ns = NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(4, uiOutput(ns("UI_1"))),
    column(6, uiOutput(ns("UI_2"))),
    column(width = 2,
           actionButton(inputId = ns("rm.filter"), label = "Filter", icon = icon("minus"), style = "position: relative; bottom: 0; right:0; top:24px;")),
    br(),
    column(width = 12, tableOutput(ns("test"))))

}

add.filter.server = function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    ns = session$ns

    output$UI_1 <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = ns("sel.col"),
                  label = "Select a column",
                  choices =  names(data %>% select_if(is.numeric)),
                  multiple = F)
    })

    col.rng = reactive({ data %>% select(one_of(input$sel.col)) })

    output$UI_2 = renderUI({

      sliderInput(inputId = ns("sel.rng"),
                  label = "Filter the range",
                  min = min(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  max = max(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  value = c(min(col.rng(), na.rm = T), max(col.rng(), na.rm = T)),
                  step = (max(col.rng(), na.rm = T) - min(col.rng(), na.rm = T)) / 100 # of breaks
      )
    })

    data.filtered = reactive({

      data %>%
        rename(Var = one_of(input$sel.col)) %>%
        arrange(Var) %>%
        filter(Var >= min(input$sel.rng), Var <= max(input$sel.rng)) %>%
        rename(!!input$sel.col := Var)

    })

    output$test = renderTable({

      data.filtered() %>%
        head()

    })

    return( data.filtered )

  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      column(width = 2, offset = 10, actionButton(inputId = "add.filter", label = "Filter", icon = icon("plus"), style = "position:relative; left:10px;")),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counter = reactiveVal(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add.filter, {

    id <- paste0("#filter_", input$add.filter)  # - 1, "-break"

    insertUI(selector = "#placeholder",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$div(
               add.filter.UI(paste0("filter_", input$add.filter)),
               id = id)
    )

    counter(input$add.filter)

    if (counter() == 1) {

      df.filtered = add.filter.server(id = paste0("filter_", input$add.filter), data = mtcars)

    } else {

      df.filtered = add.filter.server(id = paste0("filter_", input$add.filter), data = df.filtered())

    }

    output$tbl = renderTable({

      df.filtered()

    })

  })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think the solution is complicated with multiple `moduleServer` that are reference and processing the same `tableOutput(outputId = "tbl") generating the errors. Instead, I think that the `add.filter` action should only keep adding the UI while the data on the right will be filtered by all the UI input with only one reactive that would scan all input UI to gather the filter conditions.

Comment: @SinhNguyen Thank you, that's helpful. How would I scan all the input UI if I don't return it from the module server? Or are you saying that I should I return the UI inputs instead of the table (data.filtered) in my module server. Then store those inputs in lets say a reactiveValues object within the observeEvent of the apps' server component, and update that object everytime the add.filter action button is clicked with the additional filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by taking an alternative approach, as described in my comment above. The below code provides a summary table of the inputs selected by the user. All that would need to be done is to apply these filters onto the table to subset it accordingly.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

add.filter.UI = function(id) {

  ns = NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(4, uiOutput(ns("UI_1"))),
    column(6, uiOutput(ns("UI_2"))),
    column(width = 2,
           actionButton(inputId = ns("rm.filter"), label = "Filter", icon = icon("minus"), style = "position: relative; bottom: 0; right:0; top:24px;"))
    )

}

add.filter.server = function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    ns = session$ns

    output$UI_1 <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = ns("sel.col"),
                  label = "Select a column",
                  choices =  names(data %>% select_if(is.numeric)),
                  multiple = F)
    })

    col.rng = reactive({ data %>% select(one_of(input$sel.col)) })

    output$UI_2 = renderUI({

      sliderInput(inputId = ns("sel.rng"),
                  label = "Filter the range",
                  min = min(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  max = max(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  value = c(min(col.rng(), na.rm = T), max(col.rng(), na.rm = T)),
                  step = (max(col.rng(), na.rm = T) - min(col.rng(), na.rm = T)) / 100 # of breaks
      )
    })

    data.filtered = reactive({

      data.frame(Col.Nm = input$sel.col,
                 Min = min(input$sel.rng, na.rm = T),
                 Max = max(input$sel.rng, na.rm = T))

    })

    return( data.filtered )

  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      column(width = 2, offset = 10, actionButton(inputId = "add.filter", label = "Filter", icon = icon("plus"), style = "position:relative; left:10px;")),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df.filtered = reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$add.filter, {

    id <- paste0("#filter_", input$add.filter)  # - 1, "-break"

    insertUI(selector = "#placeholder",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$div(
               add.filter.UI(paste0("filter_", input$add.filter)),
               id = id)
    )

    df.filtered[[paste0("Filtered_", input$add.filter[1])]] = add.filter.server(id = paste0("filter_", input$add.filter), data = mtcars)

    output$tbl = renderTable({

      for (i in 1:input$add.filter[1]) {

        if (i == 1) {

          df = df.filtered[[paste0("Filtered_", i)]]()

        } else {

          df = rbind(df,
                     df.filtered[[paste0("Filtered_", i)]]())

        }

      }

      df

    })


  })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```